# Sequelize.js - Find object by relation id list

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

New to sequelize here and trying to grasp the concept.  I'm getting confused with syntaxes & operators.

So I have user model and a group model.  When a user post to a group, I can just use the group id: Group.findOne({id}).  However, I want to allow users to choose users they want to post the updates to, and this chosen group of users sometimes already exist as a group in our database.  How can I find the group that contains all users in the group?

For example:

User 1 post to users [2,3,4].  I want to find a group that exactly has [1,2,3,4] users as the GroupUser relation, if it exists.

I've used belongsToMany relation as shown below.

```
UserModel.belongsToMany(GroupModel, { through: 'GroupUser' });
GroupModel.belongsToMany(UserModel, { through: 'GroupUser' });
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, there are three tables users, groups, groupUsers. 
Use the following code

```
Groups.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            required: true
            model: Db.groupUsers,
            where: {
                userId: { $in: [1,2,3,4] }
            }
        },
    ]

});
```

Let me know if you want to do this without including groups users including for that can put a where condition on group findAll

Comment: Thanks for your help Rohit - Db.groupUsers is undefined.  Is there other function to grab the groupUsers model?

Comment: I can get the groupUsers model using db.model('groupUsers'), but it says groupUsers not associated with Group

Comment: I decided to add a "slug" field that comprises of all user id in a string.  Think this operation is probably cheaper than looking for the relation.  Let me know if you find any other better methods.

Comment: Hi @HenryH Sorry for the late response,  Db.groupUsers the Db is the parameter for accessing global sequelize that is created. Db is in my code it seems its different at your code. To bypass this required the groupUsers model where the above code lies